# Q: Find the partial derivatives of $f=2u+v$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ where $u=u(x,y)$ and $v=v(x,y)$ are given implicitly

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the partial derivatives of $f=2u+v$ with respect to $x$ and $y$, where $u=u(x,y)$ and $v=v(x,y)$ are differentiable functions that are given implicitly as follows:
$$u+\ln(v)=x$$
$$v-\ln(u)=y$$

I've tried to differentiate all of these equations with respect to $x$ and $y$ and did some algebra, but couldn't solve this problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might help if you show your result on what you did, as that is how you'd go about solving this problem

Comment: Are you supposed to express them in terms of $x$ and $y$ or $u$ and $v$?

Comment: @amd: I suppose, otherwise the solution is quite trivial (if you include also the partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ with respect to $x$ and $y$). However, it is not written explicitly in the problem, so I might be wrong.

Comment: I suspect that the point of the exercise is to compute $\partial u/\partial x$, &c. That’s not too painful if you can leave everything in terms of $u$ and $v$. You should be able to differentiate the expressions for $x$ and $y$ and then solve for the partials, or (what amounts to the same thing) invert the Jacobian.